# Desktop.getDesktop().print(path) doesn't work in web application

Tags: java

I have following code in web aplication

```
java.​awt.Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(path));
```

It is working with any problem on desktop aplication. But doens't in web app. And I need print the file. How to do that?

Comment: Uhm ... are you executing that code **on the server** and expect it to actually print something **on the client**? I hope you see the problem, there.

Comment: Also, you haven't told us what OS are you running, and if the OS isn't Windows, is it console based OS?

Comment: I expected that somethi ng will be printed on the server.

Comment: @iaragorn: have you ruled out a problem with the path? is it an absolute path?

Comment: path of the file? Yes this is definitely not a problem. I am checking it in the code.

Comment: Ok, if you want it to print *on the server*, then at least the approach is not fundamentally wrong. You still have the problem that `Desktop` (as the name implies) is meant for the client environment and your server is likely to run in a trimmed down environment that doesn't have access to client-related APIs/libraries/resources. What OS/environment are you running this on?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 amd java sdk 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joachim has pointed out, the Java code is running on the server, not the client so you're not going to be able to use Java to print from a web-app.

What you can use though is JavaScript `window.print()` to print the contents of the browser window.

Now you're unlikely to want to print the window contents exactly as it appears in the browser, which is where a print style-sheet comes into play - assuming your page was written to be [web-standards compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_standards) (at least when it comes to the use of CSS), you simply write a second style-sheet that controls the appearance of the page when it's printed as described [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

So in your case, you would need to render the contents of the file into the page the browser is displaying (maybe in a hidden `div`) and then the print style-sheet would hide the content displayed in the browser and show the file contents.

Comment: No i don't want anything display on the client. I want to print the file on the server, and it doesn't work.

Comment: So the web-app part of the question is irrelvant. java.awt.Desktop uses registered applications to print, much in the same way Windows does if you click print when you select a file in Explorer. To print on a server you'll need to use the javax.print API. There's an example of how to do that here - http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-print-a-text-file-with-javax.print-api.html

Answer (score 0):

The printing should be done by a javascript code, if to print in the client side. If it's done in Java the printing will be done in the server side.

A printing example in java ee: http://shyarmal.blogspot.com/2011/08/printing-example-with-java-ee.html